# What is the inspiration for the name of directive A-113 on the BNL Starliner?

Tags: pixar, wall-e

I recently came across some questions about WALL-E and Space Odyssey (featuring HAL9000), and I thought that directive A-113 (which I admit I misremembered as AE-134) and the faulty component AE-35 had a passing, albeit minor, resemblance.

It seems unlikely one inspired the other, but where does A-113 come from?

Answer (score 5):

### A113 is a common theme in pixar films.

The [directive](https://pixar.fandom.com/wiki/Directive_A-113) is reference to the "classroom number used by character animation students at the California Institute of the Arts", which was A1-13.

The Pixar fandom page, has an entire article on [A113](https://pixar.fandom.com/wiki/A113), explaining how it has appeared in most Pixar films.

Comment: https://www.dailymotion.com/video/xa7tmr